# Unable to send email in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application , I am trying to send email but unable to send it . In back-end it is showing that mail is going but in my inbox mail is not coming . 
Below is my `production.rb` file -

```
# require 'tls_smtp'
Rails.application.configure do

  config.cache_classes = false

  config.eager_load = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  config.assets.debug = true

  config.assets.digest = true

  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'mail.abc.co.in', port: 3000 }

  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "mail.abc.co.in",
    :port => 25,
    :user_name => "hrms@abc.co.in",
    :password => "***",
    :authentication => 'plain',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code for smtp setting in config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://abc.co.in' }

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "mail.abc.co.in",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => "abc.co.in",
    :user_name => "donotreply@abc.co.in",
    :password => "*********",
    :authentication => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

For gmail:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
       :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
       :port => 587,
       :domain => "gmail.com",
       :user_name => "abc@gmail.com",
       :password => "******",
       :authentication => "plain",
       :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Comment: have you setup your mail server?

Comment: make config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true and check error logs

Comment: now it is throughing following error -Net::SMTPFatalError: 553 5.7.1 <abc.co.in>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user abc

Comment: try to send mail by gmail, I have added gmail smtp setting code in anwser

Comment: have you tried gmail smtp setting? whats the error message?

Comment: remember that change in production.rb file reflects on production environment only and same as for development

Comment: again i am having the same problem . Can anyone give the perfect solution .